# Allow requesting examples in a topic (and try to direct users to do so when requesting topics)

Tags: feature-request, documentation

My idea here is twofold:

1. Users should be able to request examples in a topic.
2. Users requesting topics should be pointed towards pre-existing topics, with a button to request examples on those topics.

In my opinion, **#1** is just a natural extension of requesting topics (and perhaps a more useful one, as documentation matures and new topics are unnecessary).

**#2** would not only likely reduce the amount of duplicated topics created, but it would also reduce the requesting of narrow-scoped topics: Situations where what the user is *really* looking for is an example.

The Android tag gave me the idea for this, because it had:

- A topic called **Permissions**, which makes perfect sense
- Another topic called **RunTime Permissions**, which really should be an example on the **Permissions** topic, and not its own topic
- A proposed topic which was also about runtime permissions. I rejected it, since it not only duplicated the **RunTime Permissions** topic, but just like that one, should also have just been an example on the **Permissions** topic
- A topic request for **Handling Permissions**, which is clearly a user who really just wants *examples*, so creating a new topic would again just duplicate **Permissions**

Comment: Yes, yes, yes and yes. The topic request is being abused for requests that would be otherwise valid requests - for examples...